# 9-patch drop shadow technique works for image view but not camera preview

Tags: android

I use to following 9-patch image to create drop shadow effect.

[image]

It works pretty well for the following image view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_test"
            android:background="@drawable/dropshadow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/pic1"
            />    
</LinearLayout>
```

I am able to get a perfect shadow dropped effect. Note that, there is a 1 pixel wide red line at picture right/bottom. I purposely place the 1 pixel wide red line around picture right/ bottom, to proof there are no pixel from 9-patch image cover up my original picture.

[image]

However, when I try to apply the exact same technique on camera preview view, things getting complicated. I do a slight modification on API Demo example `com.example.android.apis.graphics.CameraActivity`

I modify the GUI view, by performing the following modification.

```
class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    // ...
    Preview(Context context) {
        // ...
        mSurfaceView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(drawable.dropshadow));
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        // ...
    }
}
```

I get the following outcome. Note that, shadow effect begin to appear, before end of picture right edge and bottom edge. Its distance is 9 pixels before reaching end of edge.

[image]

I am pretty sure I am having correct image filename `dropshadow.9.png` for both project. However, I lack of idea why the latter doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using a `SurfaceView` which provides you with a dedicated drawing surface that will not respect the content boundaries you have defined in your nine patch image.

A possible workaround would be to place your camera's `SurfaceView` on top of a slightly larger view that holds the drop shadow as a background.